# How can I stop capturing ROBOCOPY progress message when capturing PowerShell function return value?

Tags: powershell, console, return, robocopy

I used to have a function that called `robocopy` to copy a very large file and show the progress:

```
function Invoke-Robocopy {
    ROBOCOPY C:\TEMP\Source\ C:\TEMP\Destination\ Some-Very-Large-File.bak /COPY:DAT
}
```

and I called it inside another function:

```
function Invoke-SomeJob {
    Invoke-Robocopy;
}
```

This way, `robocopy` will nicely write the progress to the console.

## The Problem:

I need to return some stuff out of the function that calls `robocopy`:

```
function Invoke-RobocopyAndReturnStuff {
    ROBOCOPY C:\TEMP\Source\ C:\TEMP\Destination\ Some-Very-Large-File.bak /COPY:DAT
    return "blah-blah-blah";
}
```

And I need to use this returned stuff in my job:

```
function Invoke-SomeJobUsingStuff {
    $result = Invoke-RobocopyAndReturnStuff;
    Write-Host $result;
}
```

Now the problem is that the progress seems to be captured during the copying operation, not displayed on the console and only after the copying is complete `$result` contains the whole shebang! (... pardon my folklore).

Could someone please enlighten me on how can I achieved the desired behaviour of letting the `robocopy` output be displayed and only return what I want to return?

Comment: `start -Wait -NoNewWindow robocopy 'C:\TEMP\Source\ C:\TEMP\Destination\ Some-Very-Large-File.bak /COPY:DAT'`

Comment: Thank you @PetSerAl — I was using `Start-Process` but without the `-Wait` and `-NoNewWindow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @PetSerAl. This does the right thing:

```
function Invoke-RobocopyAndReturnStuffTheRightWay {
    Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow ROBOCOPY 'C:\TEMP\Source\ C:\TEMP\Destination\ Some-Very-Large-File.bak /COPY:DAT';
    return "blah-blah-blah";
}

function Invoke-SomeJobUsingStuffTheRightWay {
    $result = Invoke-RobocopyAndReturnStuffTheRightWay;
    Write-Host $result;
}
```

Calling `Invoke-SomeJobUsingStuffTheRightWay` now does the following:

1. Progress to the console **exactly** as `robocopy` would normally do, and
2. At the end, only the string `"blah-blah-blah"` is returned from `Invoke-RobocopyAndReturnStuffTheRightWay` and written to the console!

That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tee-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx):

```powershell
function Invoke-SomeJobUsingStuff {
    Invoke-RobocopyAndReturnStuff | Tee-Object -Variable result
    Write-Host $result;
}
```

Comment: Almost there. But this does two things:

(1) It writes to the console all the entire progress sequence of percentages, and

(2) It sends all output to `$result`, which I want to be only `"blah-blah-blah"`

Thank you for letting me know about Tee-Object anyways!